# How to work with difference lists and 3+ lists concatenation?

Tags: prolog

I have the following state in my code:
[image: One step before conc]
After the next step I get

```
(cycle) T1=[26, 25|T1]
```

In Bindings. How to solve that and make the last conc work properly? As you can see I understand how to work with a single conc, but I don't understand how to work with multiple conc's.

Comment: the purpose of predicate like conc/3 it's exactly to 'hide' the implementation details (just the dash operator, in this case). Try to express the algorithm without 'expanding' the inner details, i.e. use L1 instead of List1-T1, etc...For sure you'll gain readability.

Comment: @chac , in order to use conc with difference lists we must use the form of L1-T. Please explain briefly what do you mean.

Comment: if you post the code I'll attempt to rewrite, I'm a bit lazy now...

Comment: It's problematic now, thanks for trying to help. Maybe next week I will paste the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fisrt, you are using the same parameter to the tail of X and List (both T)

but i think it's not the only problem

TmpL1 = [[25|T1]-T1,[26|T2]-T2,[24,25|T1]-[25|T1]]
first and 3rd lists have the same tail (T1)
also 3rd list have 25 in the tail, tail should have only Unsatisfied parameter